# Validate after creating PDF/A

Tags: ghostscript

I am creating a PDF/A from a Postscript using Ghostcript 9.14.

I have a .kfp file which is used to validate the output PDF/A document. Is there any way to validate the generated PDF/A document with the .kfp validator using ghostscript?

Comment: Ghostscript does not perform validation of PDF files, and in particular does not validate subset standards (it will emit many warnings if the input file does not conform to the general PDF specification). So, no you can't do this using Ghostscript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PDF/A validator in development called [veraPDF](http://verapdf.org/home/), a result of the [Preforma](http://www.preforma-project.eu/) program, a project funded by the EU. As far as I know, it does not use the .kfp validator, but it does validate your PDF/A - sees if it is conform the different flavours of PDF/A.

Hope this can help.